# HTML tag from database not working

Tags: html, mysql, django, tags

I used django. This is my data from table company field description:

```
<b>This is description</b>
```

When I show that data in django template, the bold function not rendered. Instead, it show this on the page:

```
<b>This is description</b>
```

Why the html tag `<b>` not rendered?

Comment: HTML escaping, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape

Comment: thank you @MattDeacalionStevens it's working finally

Comment: Krisnadi, Pls accept an answer, if problem is solved. (You can write an answer yourself if none of the answer is acceptable.)

Comment: @TareqMahmood can i accept an answer from a comment?

Comment: No. You can only accept from answers. You can write an answer yourself getting it from comment. Tick the community wiki checkbox if you get it from comment. (I see you already accepted an answer?)

Comment: ok @TareqMahmood thank you for your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autoescape` in your template as follows:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ company.description }}
{% endautoescape %}
```